# Force files to stay in dentries und inodes cache on SuSe

Tags: postgresql, opensuse, inode

We have some sql queries which are rarely executed.

When running them first time after a while they take about 2 minutes, a second call takes only 800ms.

I found out when i restart postgres the querys are still fast. Only when i clear the inode cache with

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

the query is slow again. So i started to observe which files are loaded during the query:

```
inotifywait -mr  ~postgres/data/*
```

which logs on the first time several times:

```
/var/lib/pgsql/data/base/16414/ ACCESS 119232
```

it is an 1GB file:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 1,0G 22. MÃ¤r 09:53 /var/lib/pgsql/data/base/16414/119232
```

i suppose it is a file which contains the index of the table

is it possible to

1. Find out which files contain the indexes
2. Force the os to keep the files in caches?

Comment: With that sort of extreme disparity, I wonder if something is wrong with your disks?

Comment: disks seem ok "hdparm -t /var/lib/pgsql/data/base/16414/9209102.5" shows 68.92 MB/sec